# How to change TextBox placeholder text color for a specific element, not global

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

MSDN lists the styles and templates for the `TextBox` class [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj710191.aspx). I can override these theme resources by creating a `ResourceDictionary` in `App.xaml` like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBoxPlaceholderTextThemeBrush" Color="Yellow"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

but this will affect every `TextBox` in my app. **How can I set this theme for only a specific element?**

I've tried putting this dictionary in `Page.Resources` and even `TextBox.Resources` for the `TextBox` that I want to apply it to, but it doesn't work.

I *really* don't want to have to redefine the `Template` just to change this property.

---

**EDIT** Heena's answer is close, but I would also like to set different colors for light and dark themes because my textbox has a transparent background color.

I managed to achieve this by keeping `Foreground="{ThemeResource TextBoxPlaceholderTextThemeBrush}"` as part of the `Template` (so, in other words, the template is exactly the default as per MSDN) and then specifying in the page resources:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBoxPlaceholderTextThemeBrush" Color="Blue"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
        ...
    </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
</Page.Resources>
```

*but* this now means I have to put a huge `ControlTemplate` style-setter for the textbox in my page resources too, which is just an exact duplicate of the default anyway!

Does this have something to do with how `TextBoxPlaceholderTextThemeBrush` is resolved from within the `ControlTemplate`? i.e. the reason why it discovers my custom theme dictionary is because the `ControlTemplate` was defined in the same resource dictionary?

How is this supposed to be done? Should I just subclass the textbox so that all that XAML can be moved to another file (even if it is just for one textbox)?

Comment: I feel your pain ...

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you are using MSDN Textbox [Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj710191.aspx)

**Resource**
Remove Foreground Property from Contencontrol in Template`<ContentControl Foreground="{ThemeResource TextBoxPlaceholderTextThemeBrush}"/>`

```
<Page.Resources>
    <!--From MSDN : Default style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox -->
    <Style x:Key="MsdnTextboxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">          
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                 .....
                 .....
                <ContentControl x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                              Grid.Row="1"                          
                              Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                              Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                              IsTabStop="False"
                              Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                              Content="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}" 
                              IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>           
</Page.Resources>
```

**Xaml**

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBox  PlaceholderText="PlaceholderText here..." Style="{StaticResource MsdnTextboxStyle}" Margin="20"  Foreground="Red" Height="30" Width="120">
        <TextBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Resources>
    </TextBox>
    <TextBox  PlaceholderText="PlaceholderText here..." Style="{StaticResource MsdnTextboxStyle}" Margin="20"  Foreground="Red" Height="30" Width="120">
        <TextBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Resources>
    </TextBox>
    <TextBox  PlaceholderText="PlaceholderText here..." Style="{StaticResource MsdnTextboxStyle}" Margin="20"  Foreground="Red" Height="30" Width="120">
        <TextBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Resources>
    </TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

[image]

**Update**

*Resource*

Remove Foreground Property from Contencontrol in Template`<ContentControl Foreground="{ThemeResource TextBoxPlaceholderTextThemeBrush}"/>`

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ContentControlForeGround" Color="Red"></SolidColorBrush>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ContentControlForeGround1" Color="Yellow"></SolidColorBrush>
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ContentControlForeGround" Color="Blue"></SolidColorBrush>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ContentControlForeGround1" Color="SkyBlue"></SolidColorBrush>
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ContentControlForeGround" Color="Green"></SolidColorBrush>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ContentControlForeGround1" Color="Chocolate"></SolidColorBrush>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
        <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle1" TargetType="TextBox">
          .....
           <ContentControl x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}"  IsHitTestVisible="False" IsTabStop="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1"/>
           ......                                                       
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```

*xaml*

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBox  Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle1}" PlaceholderText="PlaceholderText here..."  Margin="20"  Foreground="Red" Height="30" Width="170">
        <TextBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ContentControlForeGround}"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Resources>
    </TextBox>
    <TextBox  Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle1}" PlaceholderText="PlaceholderText here..."  Margin="20"  Foreground="Red" Height="30" Width="170">
        <TextBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ContentControlForeGround1}"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Resources>
    </TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Old question I know, but I found it incredibly fruststrating that I had to create an entire copy of the TextBox style just to edit the placeholder color of one or two TextBox elements.

So I created this method, which can be used on individual TextBoxes as required:

```
public static void SetPlaceholderColor(TextBox textBox, Color color)
{
    var textBoxContentGrid = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(textBox, 0) as Grid;
    for (var i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(textBoxContentGrid); i++)
    {
        var visualChild = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(textBoxContentGrid, i);
        if ((string) visualChild.GetValue(FrameworkElement.NameProperty) != "PlaceholderTextContentPresenter") 
            continue;
        var placeHolderContentControl = visualChild as ContentControl;
        if (placeHolderContentControl != null)
            placeHolderContentControl.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(color);
    }
}
```

This should also work for PasswordBoxes, since the TextBox parameter should easily be replacable with just "FrameworkElement"