# NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle ignores overwritten AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to modify the colors of the `NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle` to fit my app design.
Unfortunately it ignores my `AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush` which wouldn't be as weird as it is if it did ignore the other brushes, too. But the Visual States etc. work just fine.

This is the `NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle` (as found in themeresources.xaml):

```
<Style x:Key="NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
          <Grid Background="Transparent" x:Name="RootGrid">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
              <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                  <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="Ellipse">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                  <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="Ellipse">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="Ellipse">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemPressedForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                  <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
              </VisualStateGroup>
              <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                  <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack" />
                  </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
              </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <Grid Height="41" Width="41">
              <Ellipse x:Name="Ellipse" Fill="{ThemeResource AppBarItemBackgroundThemeBrush}" Stroke="{ThemeResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}" StrokeThickness="2" UseLayoutRounding="False" />
              <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <PathIcon Data="F1 M 17.4126,18L 24.0752,11L 17.6558,11L 8.77931,20.4678L 8.77931,20.5322L 17.6558,30L 24.0752,30L 17.4126,23L 32,23L 32,18L 17.4126,18 Z " />
              </ContentPresenter>
            </Grid>
            <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhite" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="1.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1" />
            <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlack" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="0.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1" />
          </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
```

My custom theme (based on Theme `Light`):

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Example">
    [...]
    <Color x:Key="ForegroundColor">#FFFFFFFF</Color>
    [...]
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush" Color="{ThemeResource ForegroundColor}"/>
    [...]
</ResourceDictionary>
```

This is how I referenced the theme file right at the beginning of my App.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light" Source="ThemeLight.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
```

And finally that's how I set the theme to `Light`:

```
public App()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
    this.UnhandledException += OnUnhandledException;

    RequestedTheme = ApplicationTheme.Light;
}
```

Do I miss something or why does it ignore my value for `AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush`?

Comment: If you are using your own color then why using Color="{ThemeResource ForegroundColor}"..instead of themeresource you have to use Staticresource and in style also  used Staticresource.visit this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24429522/how-to-change-textbox-placeholder-text-color-for-a-specific-element-not-global/24432861#24432861 and please see update section

Comment: because it is a ThemeResource?
and the `NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle` is a predefined style not one of my own styles.

Comment: You can use solidcolorBrush in themedicinary like this http://prntscr.com/4artcy and if you have created your own new resourcedicinary then you need to merge http://prntscr.com/4artp5

Comment: I don't really know where you're going.
Since I'm using my own Theme which is loosely based on the theme Light (actually just for the name) I'm obviously using a ThemeDictionary where I overwrite all of the existing `SolidColorBrushes` that I need which is working fine for everything except the foreground color of said `NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle`.

Comment: Did you ever find a way? I'm having the same issue (with a more recent version of  themeresources.xaml so the keys are not the same, but the problem is the same). It doesn't seem to use it.

Comment: @SimonMourier that's been quite a while but I think I've copied the style and modified it. Can't say that for sure though.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do

```html
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Example">
    [...]
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ForegroundColor">#FFFFFFFF</SolidColorBrush>
    [...]
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush" Color="{StaticResource ForegroundColor}"/>
    [...]
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and add it to the App.xaml

```html
 <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <viewModel:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator"/>
         
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
               
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/MyStyle.xaml"/>
               
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

See it 
[Theming in Universal apps](http://www.familie-smits.com/post/2014/06/21/theming-in-universal-apps.aspx)

Comment: so how exactly would it make sense to define the color as SolidColorBrush?
It doesn't say that anywhere in the link you provided
The only difference I see is that you used MergedDictionaries instead of ThemeDictionaries.
I don't think that makes a difference and I'd prefer to use ThemeDictionaries since I'd like to add another theme later on.
anyway thanks for your answer!