# Overridding a universal app's textbox enter style

Tags: windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I'm trying to create a universal Windows 10 app.
I have this textbox, that should be invisible. The user must simply be able to enter text at the point.

The only thing I have done is set the background equal to the app's background and no border.

The result is ok, but when I enter the textbox, it becomes white, like a normal textbox.

Anyone who knows how to fix this. I want the textbox to remain the same.

Thanks in advance

Kind regards

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new Style for your textbox. It will overwrite the default template and behaviour or the default TextBox. Here is the default template: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299154.aspx

And here is code sample: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24432861/1279342

Comment: Hey, thanks for your quick response. Could you please provide me a bit more info. I'm fairly new to styles. I do not know what I have to put in the contentControl in my style.

Comment: You dont need to put anything inside. You only need to modify and the **behaviour** of the TextBox via VisualState when user active it or hover mouse over.